# No NPS (Network Policy Server) Event Logs

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, nps

Running into something very painful.  We use Microsoft's Network Policy Server, and need the Network Policy Server security event subcategory to work - specifically, event id 6273 and 6272.  NPS works, but event logs are not being written.

**We've verified the following**:

Network Policy Server is configured to log success and failure events:

```
PS > auditpol /get /subcategory:"Network Policy Server"
System audit policy

Category/Subcategory                      Setting
Logon/Logoff
  Network Policy Server                   Success and Failure

PS > cat $env:systemroot\security\audit\audit.csv | select-string net

,System,Audit Network Policy Server,{0cce9243-69ae-11d9-bed3-505054503030},Success and Failure,,3
```

We've confirmed that NPS is configured to log these:

- Open NPS > Right click NPS (Local) > Properties > General Tab, both Successful and Rejected authentication requests boxes are checked

**Unacceptable workarounds**:

Text logs.  They are being written without issue, but we have a variety of services and tools configured to use the event log data that *should be working*

**What we've tried**:

- Restarting :shrug:
- Manually disable network policy server audit policy, re-enable
- Disable network policy server configuration to log successful and rejected authentication requests
- Pair the above with restarting eventlog and ias services

Regardless of any changes, no NPS events are written to the event log

I'm sort of at a loss, outside of diving into procmon, but I have no idea when/where this might be failing, so something so verbose may not be super helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: That's pretty peculiar - has this every worked before? Are you seeing other security events (I'm assume so)?

Comment: Yes, it's quite peculiar and somewhat infuriating! It functions now on a nearly identically configured server - this is one of two domain controllers that use NPS - all other events categories are functioning, it's just that NPS on this one server is not generating windows event logs.  Even more fun?  We ran into this on a 2012 R2 domain controller some time ago, just... never had the time to look into it.  At this point, will remove/add the role and report back...

Comment: Maybe this helps - export the config on the working NPS server and import it on the broken one? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/nps/nps-manage-export

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I would try setting the logging to disabled, then enable it again (possibly with a reboot before enabling it again)

From an elevated command prompt:

To disable

```
auditpol /set /subcategory:"Network Policy Server" /success:disable /failure:disable
```

To enable

```
auditpol /set /subcategory:"Network Policy Server" /success:enable /failure:enable
```

Comment: I thought the same!  No luck : (

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share the solution for the issue regarding the missing event viewer logs in "Network Policy and Access Services" on Windows Server 2019.

Solution:

1. CMD > sc sidtype IAS unrestricted
2. Reboot the server
3. Attempt the connection again

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-10/windows-server-2019-nps-radius-no-event-viewer-logs-solution/m-p/3789866

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/548339)